# Warning: Illegal string offset in Custom in custom meta boxes

Tags: php, wordpress, warnings

In my custom post-type, I am building a multidimensional array meta-box with multiple `input`s, with below code:

```
<?php
    $services = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'services', true);

    foreach ((array) $services as $service) {
        echo '<div class="inside">
        <div>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="service[][title]" value="' . $service['title'] . '">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Type</label>
         <input type="text" name="service[][type]" value="' . $service['type'] . '">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Content</label>
            <textarea name="service[][text]">' . $service['text'] . '</textarea>
        </div>';
    }
    exit;
    ?>
```

It is throwing the Warning:

> Illegal string offset 'title' and same warning for `'type'` & `'text'`.

I have tried double-quotes as well also.

Using the below code to store the data, if it helps:

```
function service_save_meta_box_data($post_id) {
// store custom fields values
if (isset($_REQUEST['services'])) {
 update_post_meta($post_id, 'services', sanitize_text_field($_POST['service']));
}
}
add_action('save_post_service', 'service_save_meta_box_data');
```

Comment: Just make var_dump($service); after foreach() line to see what the problem is.

Comment: `string '' (length=0)`

Comment: Issue is `foreach ((array) $services as $service)`, Only in `foreach` loop I am getting this warning.

Comment: it means the problem is in saving process.  remove sanitize_text_field from 
 update_post_meta($post_id, 'services', sanitize_text_field($_POST['service']));. and test it again. if it works, then apply sanitize_text_field to array elements by using array_map() function